# transition not working in toggleclass while adding in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .expanded {
        width: 200px
    }
</style>

<body>

    <button id="but">Button</button>
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col></col>
            <col></col>
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>

    </table>


<script>
    $('#but').click(function(){
       if($('table col').hasClass("expanded"))
          $('table col').toggleClass('expanded',1000,"easeOutSine");
       else
         $('table col').toggleClass('expanded',1000,"easeOutSine");
    });
</script>
```

> In this above example transition not working while adding toggle class
>   in jquery in table.please help me how to do that.please don't change
>   structure.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vbpradeep/psn2kt5n/1/)

Comment: You don't need to check if it has class before doing a toggleClass as that will automatically remove the class if it's there and add it if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a set width to begin with, here is an example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psn2kt5n/2/)

```
table col {
    width: 75px; /* added this */
    -webkit-transition:width .8s ease;
    ...
```

Alternatively, you could use jQuery's `animate()` to change the width, in this case you would remove the css transitions: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psn2kt5n/3/)

```
if ($col.hasClass("expanded")) {
    $col.removeClass('expanded');
    $col.animate({"width": ""}, "slow");
} else {
    $('table col').addClass('expanded');
    $col.animate({"width": "200px"}, "slow");
}
```

As for your edit to using `toggleClass`, part of the reason it wasn't working was because you didn't source jQueryUI... the other part seems to be that it doesn't work with col. It works if I add a width on the table, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/psn2kt5n/5/)... or on the `td` which should have the same affect you want, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/psn2kt5n/6/).

Comment: this is my structure how to give transition for that

Comment: @PradeepKumar, like I mentioned at the end of my answer, you can use `td` in place of `col`, see here http://jsfiddle.net/psn2kt5n/10/